# ImportError: dlopen failed: site-packages/grpc/_cython is 64-bit instead of 32 bit when packaging for Android

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer

I'm getting the following `ImportError` when I try to package my app for Android and am getting the below error. I'm using Ubuntu on VirtualBox.

```
ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/org.test.myapp/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/grpc/_cython/cygrpc.so" is a 64-bit instead of a 32-bit
```

More of the Traceback here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/33rOE.jpg

Comment: This indicates that grpc has compiled components which have probably been built for your desktop. It needs a build recipe for python-for-android to compile it correctly.

Comment: Ah OK, I have found this recipe for grpcio but not sure what I need to do to be able to add it to my requirements line https://github.com/hpsaturn/p4a_grpcio_recipe/blob/master/__init__.py